# How to add '#' in starting of line where particular string occur using ansible

Tags: ansible

My host file contain a string "DEST" like

```
    [app]
    tera-DESTi-67263
```

I just want to add:
'#tera-DESTi-67263 where DEST occurs'.

How to do this using ansible?

Comment: Do you mean you are wanting to use Ansible to modify an Ansible inventory file? What are you trying to achieve with this? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using lininfile but yet not able to perform this. I just want to comment a line where DEST occur.

Comment: Edit your question to show your playbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [the `lineinfile` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html):

```
- lineinfile:
    dest=/path/to/file.ini
    regexp='^(\s*[^#]*)DEST(.*)$'
    line='#\1DEST\2'
    backrefs=yes
```